# Update title of Dialog from the source of Iframe

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I made a dialog,iframe

```
var $frm = $('<iframe />').attr('id','ifrmTV'), 
$dialog = $('<div />').dialog({ autoOpen: false, width: 'auto', hight: 'auto' });
```

then after some data processing I set $frm source and show the dialog something like:

```
$frm.attr('src', 'Http/WMP.htm').appendTo($dialog);
$dialog.dialog({title: 'title'}).dialog('open');
```

I would like to know if there is a way in WMP.htm code to change the title of the dialog. jquery_UI generate a span with the class ui-dialog-title but it shouldn't be accessible from the WMP.htm. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page `Http/WMP.htm` that you are loading inside the iframe should also load jQuery. This is not necessary, but will make consistent when looking for the `ui-dialog-title` element.

**Note**: [read this](http://www.semwisdom.com/blog/lowercase-uppercase-seo#axzz1RhZcMk69) about lowercase and uppercase urls.

Now, inside your iframe, you can access the parent container using `window.parent` and, using jQuery, access any element with `$('selector', window.parent.document)`. Now, the page that you load inside your iframe should know it's owned dialog element id, so it can find it back. While you can accomplish this in various ways, I'll just assume you have one dialog for this iframe loading `Http/WMP.htm`. So, you should be able to do something like

```
var $frm = $('<iframe />').attr('id','ifrmTV'), 
    $dialog = $('<div />').attr('id', 'dlgTV')
                 .dialog({ autoOpen: false, width: 'auto', hight: 'auto' });

//...

$frm.attr('src', 'Http/WMP.htm').appendTo($dialog.dialog({title: 'Loading...'}));
$dialog.dialog('open');
```

And inside the page `WMP.htm` :

```
$('#dlgTV', parent.document).prev().find('.ui-dialog-title').html('Some title');
```

Comment: Thanks Yanick the perfect solution with parent.document as context.

Answer (score -2):

> можно использовать d3
>       я получил желаемый результат так:

---

You can use d3 I got the desired result as follows:

```
d3.select(parent.document).select('span.ui-dialog-title').text('нужный текст');
```

Comment: [Stack Overflow generally works in English](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/); please make sure your post is as useful as possible to others by translating it.